# Complex inequality: find the max value.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Given that
$|a|=1$

$|b-2|=3$

$|c-5|=6 $
find the max value of$ |2a-3b-4c|$
where a,b,c are complex numbers.

I solved it like this

$|b-2|≤|b|+|-2|$

$3\le |b| + 2$

$1\le |b|$

$3\le |3b|$

Similarly i got

$4≤|4c|$

Then i wrote

$|2a-3b-4c|≤|2a|+|3b|+|4c|$

$|2a-3b-4c|≤2+3+4$

$|2a-3b-4c|≤9$

But  9 isn't the right answer.

On the other hand if I write
$-|2|$ instead of 
$|-2|$ in

$|b-2|≤|b|+|-2|$

And similarly in the case of c as well

I get the answer as 61 which is right.

Comment: what have you tried thus far in solving this problem

Comment: @phdmba7of12 i used triangle inequality.

Comment: @Janstew you must show your work.

Comment: Can we write |b-2|<=|b|+|-2|

Comment: i solved it like this

Comment: i solved it like this |b-2|≤|b|+|-2| which gave me 3≤|3b| similarly i got 4≤|4c| then i wrote |2a-3b-4c|≤|2a|+|3b|+|4c| and then put the minimum values of rhs terms to get maximum lhs which i got 9. but i dont think thats the write answer.

Comment: @Janstew please put all this data in your answer by using the edit button

Answer (score 1):

Note,

$$|2a-3b-4c|\le|2a|+|3b|+|4c|$$
$$=2|a|+3|b-2+2|+4|c-5+5|$$
$$\le |2a|+3(|b-2|+2)+4(|c-5|+5)$$
 $$=2\cdot 1+3\cdot(3+2)+4\cdot(6+5)=61$$

where the maximum value $61$ occurs at $a=-1$, $b=5$ and $c=11$.

Comment: Can you check what i did.

Comment: @Janstew - From $|2a-3b-4c|≤|2a|+|3b|+|4c|$ to $|2a-3b-4c|≤2+3+4$ in your derivation is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your answer didn’t work was because you maximised $a,b$ and $c$ separately (that too incorrectly).

Now such an approach might have worked, if there was $+$ sign everywhere. Since we don’t, you have to solve it differently.

$$|2a-3b-4c|\le |2a|+|3b|+|4c|$$

Now maximise each term separately, for example 
$$|3b|\le 3|b-2+2|$$

$$\le 3||b-2|+2|$$
$$\le 3|(3+2)|$$
$$\le 15$$

Do the same for all the three terms.

Comment: I agree that maximizing separately can affect the answer but how can u say that I maximised a,b,c separately 'incorrectly'?

Comment: If you check the other answer, you can see that he arrived at values other than $1$

Comment: The method of finding the maxima itself was incorrect, because clearly the maximum value of $b=5$

Comment: can u elaborate why is that wrong what i did?

Comment: If you square both sides, ie. $|b-2|^2=9$ then $b^2-4b-5=0$. Solve the quadratic

Comment: it's a complex number

Comment: That’s what the question says, but I don’t think it’s very accurate. If $b$ was a complex number, there is no way to maximise it, since inequalities don’t exist for complex numbers. It probably means that $b$ can be complex or real

Comment: You can accept the answer if you found it helpful